# add a float value to a tuple

Tags: list, tuples

I get x y coordinates from a vision tool as text(string). I need to add a constant value
 to every x - element in this string.

with this statements a get a tuple of the original values and the command of my vision-
 tool needs a tuple as argument

```
above=GetValue('ObererBogen.FittedPoints')
above=above.replace('(((','((')
above=above.replace('),),)','))')
above=eval(above)
```

now I have a tuple named above with x,y-coordinates.
 But how add a constant value to each x-value ?

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would probably be to use [`numpy`](http://www.scipy.org/).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.add((3, 1), (2, 0))
>>> a
array([5, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> tuple(a)
(5, 1)
```

I separated the adding and converting to `tuple()` steps just to show, but if you were actually doing it you could just do `tuple(np.add(tuple1, tuple2))`.

Otherwise, you'd have to do something clunky like `a = (a[0] + 5, a[1])` (which I've always disliked for a variety of reasons, despite this technically being the easiest solution), or either subclass the `tuple` type to make a type where addition applied to the elements rather than being concatenation or use the `collections.namedtuple` factory and the `_replace` method of instances of the class created with it.